# Vue.js - Props are undefined in component method

Tags: django, vue.js, vue-component

I am beginning to integrate Vue.js in to a Django project (multi-page application).

To start I am trying to create a simple logout component that will POST to the route for logout. The endpoint for the route comes from Django's `url` template tag.

The endpoint prop is `undefined` within the component method. Though it is available within the component template. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Django Template**

```
<div id="logout">
    <logout endpoint="{% url 'account_logout' %}"
            csrf_token="{{ csrf_token }}"></logout>
</div>
{% render_bundle 'logout' %}
```

**logout.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Logout from './Logout.vue'


new Vue({
    el: '#logout',

    components: {
        Logout
    }
});
```

**Logout.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span class="logout-link"
              @click="performLogout">

            Logout
        </span>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        name: 'logout',

        props: [
            'csrf_token',
            'endpoint'
        ],

        data () {
            return {
            }
        },

        methods: {
            performLogout: event => {
                console.log(`Endpoint: ${this.endpoint}`); // <-- undefined
                // this.$http.post(this.endpoint);
            }
        }
    }
</script>


<style>
    .logout-link {
        padding: 3px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a scoping issue of `this`.

`this` in your method does not point to the vue instance. That's why you can't access `endpoint` prop using `this.endpoint`.

Try it like this :

```
methods: {
    performLogout(event) {
        console.log(`Endpoint: ${this.endpoint}`); 
                // this.$http.post(this.endpoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I now see there is a warning in the docs to not use an arrow function to define a method. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods

Comment: Hi Vamsi, would you have any advice for a new question of mine? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829369/webpack-cannot-import-vue-from-instance-saved-in-another-directory